# Plesk nginx config for every domain and subdomain

Tags: nginx, plesk, vhosts

I use Plesk and I have three domains and subdomains with different ngnix configs. 
At the moment I change the ngnix config in the /etc/ngnix/plesk.conf.d/vhost/manual after every update, because my changes are being overwritten by the httpdmng.

Now to my question; Can I create a separate template in /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/folder  for each domain?

Example:
`mydomain1` use the template from `/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/mydomain1/nginxDomainVirtualHost.php`

`mydomain2` use the template from `/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/mydomain2/nginxDomainVirtualHost.php`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plesk really shouldn't have its core edited. When you need domain level config changes there's a file you need to edit outside that file. Under Apache that file was called `vhost.conf` under the directory for your domain. It would then append that to the base config. It looks like nginx uses a similar process.

Based on [this post](https://talk.plesk.com/threads/nginx-configuration-for-vhosts.260814/) here's what you need to do

> Here steps how to add custom include in nginx virtual host config:
>
> mkdir /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/custom/domain
>
> cp
>   /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/default/domain/nginxDomainVirtualHost.php
>   /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/custom/domain/
>
> add in
>   /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/custom/domain/nginxDomainVirtualHost.php:
>
> ```
>  <?php if (file_exists($VAR->domain->physicalHosting->vhostDir . '/conf/nginx.conf')): ?> 
>  include <?php echo $VAR->domain->physicalHosting->vhostDir;?>/conf/nginx.conf; 
>  <?php endif ?>
> ```
>
> /usr/local/psa/admin/bin/httpdmng --reconfigure-all # to apply new
>   configuration for all domains
>
> As result, if domain has conf/nginx.conf - it will be included into
>   virtual host config.

Answer (score 5):

In case someone come across this post, for plesk 12 you just create **vhost_nginx.conf** in the **/var/www/vhost/DOMAINE_NAME/conf/** directory and then run **/usr/local/psa/admin/bin/httpdmng** to get the file included in **last_nginx.conf**

Comment: The problem is that creating this file doesn't overwrite what's already in place by the defaults. For example, `location / {}` is already set by the default files. So you can't do ANYTHING to change it. Atleast I haven't figured out how yet without editing some things.